# wordpress plugin require_once file - can't user wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I read a lot about the `require_once` in stackoverflow.

But no anwser solved my problem.

I've a plugin with two files.

```
dmd_main.php //main file

dmd_second.php //some WP functions
```

In my main file I've included this line:

```
require_once (plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/dmd_second.php');
```

But on my second file I still got the errormessage:

> Call to undefined function get_option()

I read that this is the right way to work with the wordpress functions or not?

I've tried a lot and this code will work if I include it in my second file:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'wp-config.php' );
```

But this solution is realy bad.

Can somebody explain me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you use `get_option()` in the same way in the first file, just as a test?